# restsharp response contains nothing

Tags: c#, restsharp

I am trying to make a simple request to get the html of a website but restsharp doesn't return any response in the `response.Content`:

```
using System;
using RestSharp;

namespace AMD
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string response2;
            
            var client = new RestClient("https://google.com");
            var request = new RestRequest("Method.GET");
            
            request.AddHeader("Host:", "google.com");
            request.AddHeader("User-Agent:", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64;");
            request.AddHeader("Accept:", "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8");
            request.AddHeader("Accept-Language:", "en-US,en;q=0.5");
            request.AddHeader("Accept-Encoding:", "gzip, deflate, br");
            request.AddHeader("Connection:", "keep-alive");
            request.AddHeader("Cache-Control:", "max-age=0");

            IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
            
            response2 = response.Content.ToString();
            
            Console.WriteLine(response2);     // doesn't print anything
            
            Console.ReadLine();               // so console doesn't close
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two things:

- when creating the IRestREquest - you need to pass in an **enum** value - **NOT** a string:

  ```
  var request = new RestRequest(Method.GET);
  ```

  A string would be interpreted as a **resource** to fetch - and not surprisingly, there's nothing to fetch at `https://google.com/Method.GET` ....
- *all* of your HTTP headers **must NOT** contain a trailing `:`

  ```
  request.AddHeader("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate, br");
                                  **** absolutely NO colon here!
  ```

So try this code:

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
 {
     string response2;

     var client = new RestClient("https://google.com");
     var request = new RestRequest(Method.GET);

     request.AddHeader("Host", "google.com");
     request.AddHeader("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64;");
     request.AddHeader("Accept", "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8");
     request.AddHeader("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.5");
     request.AddHeader("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate, br");
     request.AddHeader("Connection", "keep-alive");
     request.AddHeader("Cache-Control", "max-age=0");

     IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);

     response2 = response.Content.ToString();

     Console.WriteLine(response2);     // doesn't print anything

     Console.ReadLine();
 }
```

**Suggestion**: once you've made the call and received the response - **check** to see if it's successful. Since if it wasn't successful (for whatever reason), there's no point in trying to deserialize or work with the response anyway.....

```
IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);

if (response.IsSuccessful)
{
    // do your stuff here
}
```